# Retrieve Azure VNET subnet IDs with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to retrieve/pull the subnet IDs from an existing VNET in Azure using the **azurerm_virtual_network** data source.  My code below is not working as expected.  Any help is appreciated.

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                 = "my-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "my-resource-group"
}

output "my-subnets-ids" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets.id}"
}
```

I am receiving the following error when I execute.

```
output.my-subnets: Resource 'data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet' 
does not have attribute 'subnets.id' for variable
'data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets.id'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would combine this with the [subnet](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html) data resource and use it to get all your ids. This code is close, I don't have time to pull it up and work out the full syntax.

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
    name                 = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets[count.index]}"
    virtual_network_name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
    resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name}"
    count = "${count(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets)}"
}

 output "subnet_ids" {
     value = "${data.azurerm_subnet.test.*.id}"
 }
```

Comment: that kinda does the trick, but doesnt make a lot of sense, since you would need a DATA block for every subnet, easier to just use existing vnet data block

Comment: You don't have to add a data block for every subnet as I am using the count and interpolation to get it. It does stink.

Comment: Jamie is right.  This will pull all the subnets in the VNET without having a data block for every subnet.  Very clean.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to reference the result using the subnet names rather than an arbitrary index you can use the following:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet_ski_01" {
  name                 = module.vnet_ski_01.name
  resource_group_name  = module.azurerm_resource_group_net_01.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_ski_01_subnets" {
  for_each            = toset(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_ski_01.subnets)
  name                 = each.value
  virtual_network_name = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_ski_01.name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_ski_01.resource_group_name}"
}
```

You can then refer to your subnets by name for example (`AzureBastionSubnet` is the subnet name):

```
output "subnet_bastion_address_space" {
     value = data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_ski_01_subnets["AzureBastionSubnet"].address_prefix
 }
```

I used this approach to pass all my subnets into an NSG module so I could reference subnet address spaces in my NSG rules

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/virtual_network.html#subnets) it only contains list of names of the subnets, not their ids, so you would need to construct those manually. easiest way - take vnet.id and add `'/subnets/${each subnet name goes here}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by:

```
data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet.*.id
```

It will be a list, to get the first member, use:

```
data.azurerm_virtual_network.virtualNetwork1.subnet.*.id[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this based on Jamies proposed solution and this code works :)

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "virtualSubnets1" {
    name                 = data.azurerm_virtual_network.virtualNetwork1.subnets[count.index]
    virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.virtualNetwork1.name
    resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.virtualNetwork1.resource_group_name
    count                = length(data.azurerm_virtual_network.virtualNetwork1.subnets)
}


output "virtualnetwork_subnets_ids" {
  value = data.azurerm_subnet.virtualSubnets1.*.id
}
```

...and then you can retrieve the subnets using something like this

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg_mapping1" {
  subnet_id                 = data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.virtualnetwork_subnets_ids[1]
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}
```